# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in autoregressive model, python

Tags: python, valueerror

I am reading book regarding time-series forecasting with phython.
And one problem came up when I typed the python code in autoregressive model.

The python script is below,

```
def generate_timeseries(signal, noise=None):
    time_sampler = ts.TimeSampler(stop_time=20)
    regular_time_samples = time_sampler.sample_regular_time(num_points=100)
    timeseries = ts.TimeSeries(signal_generator=signal, noise_generator=noise)
    samples, signals, errors = timeseries.sample(regular_time_samples)
    return samples, regular_time_samples, signals, errors
```

```
signal = ts.signals.AutoRegressive(ar_param=[1.5, -0.75])
samples, regular_time_samples, signals, errors = generate_timeseries(signal=signal)
```

And error message came up as below.

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

Please give me any advice to solve this problem.

Thank you.

I have read solutions in this site ot any blogs related to this error, but couldn't find the exact solution.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message, so we can see exactly where the error happened.

Comment: Also please show your import statements.  Not everyone will know what `ts` is.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you should set an array element with a sequence. Instead of assigning `ar_param=[1.5, -0.75]`, try using `ar_param=[1.5 -0.75]`, and it should work. Here's the complete code:

```py
import timesynth as ts

# Initializing TimeSampler
time_sampler = ts.TimeSampler(stop_time=20)

# Sampling regular time samples
regular_time_samples = time_sampler.sample_regular_time(num_points=100)

# Initializing AR model
ar_p = ts.signals.AutoRegressive(ar_param=[1.5 -0.75])
ar_p_series = ts.TimeSeries(signal_generator=ar_p)
samples = ar_p_series.sample(regular_time_samples)

plt.plot(regular_time_samples, samples[0])
```

[image]

Comment: However, I doubt "1.5 -0.75" is a reasonable parameter value here. This will not be an error, but it very likely does nothing.

Comment: @RalfUlrich What's your suggestion, then?